# Unable to enter passphrase for encyption

Tags: boot

I have just installed 13.10 and am unable to enter the passphrase for the cryptsetup,
it does not seem to recognise the keyboard, but works perfectly fine on the GNB GRUB screen
before hand

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your kernel doesn't have the correct USB driver(s); whether that be the host controller or the HID driver is difficult to say.

You could try to boot from installable media and then mount the root partion into /mnt there, and then rebuild your kernel/initram.

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/229732) bug might be relevant.

Comment: Cheers will give that a try